# What is the equivalent of list when using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

When I want to copy a list without linking to the same object I have to call list. So:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = list(a)

a == b
True

a is b
False
```

What would be the equivalent when I have a numpy array

```
import numpy
a = numpy.ones(4)

b = XXX(a)?
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [ndarray.copy()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html)?

Comment: In Python 3, `list` objects also have a `copy` method, which I think beats all the other methods for clarity of intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `copy`-method:

```
b = a.copy()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `[:]` pattern to copy an array or list (actually, just for lists and not for arrays.  See Update below).

```
a = np.ones(4)
b = a[:]

>>> b
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])

>>> id(a)
4606143744

>>> id(b)
4606143984
```

**Timings**

```
a = np.random.randn(1000000)

%timeit -n 1000 a.copy()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 ms per loop

%timeit -n 1000 a[:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 659 ns per loop
```

**Update**

I would normally delete an erroneous post like this, but I am leaving it because I believe it is instructive.

Works as expected for lists.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a[:]
b[2] = 0

>>> a
[1, 2, 3]

>>> b
[1, 2, 0]
```

But as pointed out by @ Divakar, this does not appear to work for Numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = a[:]
b[2] = 0

>>> a
array([1, 2, 0])

>>> b
array([1, 2, 0])

>>> id(a)
4600986400

>>> id(b)
4606142624
```

Best to explicitly use the `copy()` method (e.g. `b = a.copy()`).

Comment: It also seems to work. But hasn't this being disavowed when used about lists? I can't remember why? I read somewhere using list is better... Anyway. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Isn't `a[::1]`a view of `a` as `np.may_share_memory(a[::1],a)` returns `True`?

Comment: "A return of True does not necessarily mean that the two arrays share any element. It just means that they might."  But in fact it appears that you may be correct...

Comment: But copy() or ndarray.copy()?

Comment: @B_Furtado Yes, that is what I was implying.

Comment: When you equate two arrays their id's might differ but you need to check the id's of its elements. Then @Divakar's comment become clear. id(a[0]) == id(b[0]) gives True

Comment: Yes, I agree and understand.  It just took me by surprise, so I've left this post as an example of how NOT to do it as commented in the Update.